# Trouble attempting to upload file to FTP using wininet [Id returned 1 exit status]

Tags: c++, gcc, ftp, wininet

I got this code from another post, but when attempting to compile it shows the following errors:

[image]

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")

int main() {
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "host", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "user", "passwd", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "D:\\test.txt", "\\test.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    std::cout << "File Uploaded." << std::endl;
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using windows 7 x86 and gcc 10.3.

Comment: Looks like you are missing some libraries, thus the symbols can't be found. I'm not that familiar with windows cpp compiling so it's a guess, but did you tell your compiler where to look for wininet (unless it's a standard lib) ?

Answer (score 2):

gcc does not support `#pragma comment(lib, <filename>)`. You can use gcc's `-Werror=unknown-pragmas` command-line parameter to verify that.

You will need to use gcc's `-l` command-line parameter to link to import libraries, like `wininet.lib`.